# Changing shape using System.Drawing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drawing, system.drawing

How can we change the shape of a Windows Forms `Form`? I mean, like totally mangle the thing.

Something like this? And is `System.Drawing` the best way to go about changing the shape of things, like forms? Or is there something else that I would need to use instead?

[image]

I'm not after code or anything, just some helpful references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSDN has a reference page on [How to: Create Nonrectangular Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k15y9et.aspx).  It walks through the entire process.

Comment: Hmm, that Title rings a bell from about 2 years ago. Thanks @Reed, am checking that out now.